# How can I use private gems(GemFury) in a docker container?

Tags: ruby, git, docker, bundle, gem-fury

I'm trying to run some ruby scripts for automating exports. Since these run remotely we build them in a Docker container and push them to iron worker.

We use GemFury for hosting some essential private gems for these scripts. 
To keep the credentials for GemFury out of Git we use a global bundle config `bundle config gem.fury.io MY_SECRET_TOKEN`.

How can I set the config for bundle so it will pull in gems from GemFury without having them show in source control?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're doing `docker build` on each build or have a static Docker image as the build environment that produces other artifacts for your worker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the global bundle config property as an application specific property. Push the changes to the public repository. Update the `SECRET_TOKEN` value in the bundle-config file (`$APP_DIR/.bundle/config`) and run the `$ git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>` command to remove the file from git tracking and prevent updating the actual SECRET_TOKEN value in the public repository.

```
$ bundle config --local gem.fury.io SECRET_TOKEN
$ git commit -a -m "adding application bundle config properties"
$ git push origin master
$ bundle config --local gem.fury.io d1320f07ac50d1033e8ef5fbd56adf360ec103b2
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged $APP_DIR/.bundle/config
```

This creates a *template* file on the public repository. Provide instructions to repository contributors to add the secret token and execute the same --assume-unchanged command.

### Example Files

*$APP_DIR/.bundle/config* file on public github repo:

`---
BUNDLE_GEM__FURY__IO: MY_SECRET_TOKEN`

*$APP_DIR/.bundle/config* file a local machine

`---
BUNDLE_GEM__FURY__IO: d1320f07ac50d1033e8ef5fbd56adf360ec103b2`

See [bundle-cofig](http://bundler.io/v1.11/man/bundle-config.1.html) documentation for clarification and more detail

NOTE: The disadvantage to this approach is two fold:

1. Developers who clone the repository and need the `SECRET_TOKEN` value will have to obtain it by some external manual process (good security practices, but a pain to set up)
2. If you need to add more bundle-config properties, you will have to run `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>` to enable tracking, and revert all of the *private* values to their pseudo values. This template method, also risks that contributors forget to disable tracking on the file and push their private values to the public repo (but at least they won't be your secret values)

The advantage of this template approach is that you are giving the developers as much as possible to be able to start contributing to the repository.